# React - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using a website my father-in-law has asked me to build as an excuse to learn React. I'm not a natural JavaScript developer (happier in the backend) and know that I've probably got some recursive element to my code below but I just can't see it. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Container, Segment, Grid, Image, Card, Divider, Header } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import publicationData from '../data/publicationData';

const Publication = (props) => (
  <Card>
      <Image src={props.img_url} style={{ height: "350px", width: "auto", margin: "15px auto"}}/>
      <Card.Content style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
        <Card.Header >{props.title}</Card.Header>
      </Card.Content>
  </Card>
);



class Publications extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { books: publicationData, currentBook: publicationData[0] };
        this.changeCurrentBook.bind(this);

    }
    changeCurrentBook(e) {
        this.setState({ currentBook: e });
    }
  render() {
    return(
            <Segment basic>
                <Container>
                    <Grid stackable>
                        <Grid.Row divided>
                            <Grid.Column width={8}>
                                <Image src={ this.state.currentBook.img_url } centered/>
                            </Grid.Column>
                            <Grid.Column width={8} verticalAlign="middle">
                                <Header content={ this.state.currentBook.title} />
                                <p>{ this.state.currentBook.blurb }</p>
                            </Grid.Column>
                        </Grid.Row>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid.Row>
                    <Divider />
                    <Grid.Column>
                        <Card.Group itemsPerRow={4} doubling stackable>
                            { this.state.books.map((publication) => {
                                  return (
                                    <Publication 
                                        title={publication.title}
                                      blurb={publication.blurb}
                                      img_url={publication.img_url}
                                      key={publication.title}
                                      onClick={ this.changeCurrentBook(publication) }
                                    />
                                  )
                                }) 
                            }
                        </Card.Group>
                    </Grid.Column>
                    </Grid.Row>
                </Container>
            </Segment>
        );
    }
}

export default Publications;
```

Comment: could you please add a logging statement inside the function `changeCurrentBook`, to check whether even if it is getting executed or not , on the `onclick` event.

Comment: @RaghavGarg Good call, it's not even firing.

Comment: so, when adding `onClick` to the `Publication` component, you are just passing another prop; you would have to use(bind) it inside your `Publication` component to some `element` to actually fire it.

Comment: @RaghavGarg Given that this question has technically been answered, I'll probably move this current problem over to a new question so as not to clutter this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you write

```
onClick={ this.changeCurrentBook(publication) }
```

the function will be executed immediately and the computed value will be passed to the `onClick`. 
What you need is to run a code which immediately return a function which will be invoked on click. To do so, change `onClick` invocation inside your `Publication` component from

```
onClick={ this.changeCurrentBook(publication) }
```

to

```
onClick = {() => this.changeCurrentBook(publication)}
```

As a further improvement, it's also worth noting that writing an arrow function inside the render has some performance implications. In fact, every time `Publication` component is rendered, it will generate a new identical `onClick` function and this in turn will force the component to re-render.

To avoid extra useless renderings, let's change the handler to return a function which will be invoked on click:

```
changeCurrentBook(e) {
  return function() { 
    this.setState({ currentBook: e }); 
  }  
}
```

This way we don't need any arrow function inside render method and we won't have any extra rendering:

```
 onClick={ this.changeCurrentBook(publication) }
```

See [here](https://medium.com/netscape/react-performance-anti-pattern-creating-functions-in-render-ddeb5ebd2933) for further explanations.

Comment: Thank you, that prevented the maximum call stack size exceeded. Unfortunately the code doesn't seem to be doing what I want it to though - the onClick is not updating the page. Any chance you can see what's wrong there too? Will accept your answer once the time limit has progressed.

Comment: a small explanation would be nice to add, so that OP would understand where he was making a mistake.

Comment: Very well explained. Cheers for the performance improvement explanation too.

Answer (score 1):

Write your `Publication` component's `onClick` like this

```
<Publication 
   title={publication.title}
   blurb={publication.blurb}
   img_url={publication.img_url}
   key={publication.title}
   onClick={ () => this.changeCurrentBook(publication) }
/>
```

Also you need to bind your method like this

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { books: publicationData, currentBook: publicationData[0] };
  this.changeCurrentBook = this.changeCurrentBook.bind(this);
}
```